# Accessing angularjs factory data outside promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory named `readingService` the factory method `GetLastSyncTimestamp` return a DateTime from a web service, after calling the factory I have assign return DateTime in `$scope.lastSyncTimestamp` variable, but problem  is inside the promise I can get the DateTime correctly

```
 readingService.GetLastSyncTimestamp($scope.id).then(function(d) {
            $scope.lastSyncTimestamp = d.data;
            console.log($scope.lastSyncTimestamp);
        });
```

but outside the promise I don't get any data

```
 readingService.GetLastSyncTimestamp($scope.id).then(function(d) {
            $scope.lastSyncTimestamp = d.data;
        });

console.log($scope.lastSyncTimestamp);
```

is there any way to get data outside the promise ?

Comment: sure use a service, but the problem is related to the async call of the promise. When you try to print the value is actually not set

Comment: yes problem is the async call, but need a way to get it outside

Comment: use the service below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a service

```
  .service('DataService', function () {
            var service = {};
            service.defaultvalue= "1";
            return service;
        })
```

and inject it in the controller. 
Then you can use it in the promise like:

```
dataservice.lastSyncTimestamp = d.data;
```

and also outside will be working.

example:
https://github.com/leader80/angularjs-dataservice/blob/master/js/dataService.js

Answer (score 1):

In this example:

```
readingService.GetLastSyncTimestamp($scope.id).then(function(d) {
    $scope.lastSyncTimestamp = d.data;
});

console.log($scope.lastSyncTimestamp);
```

The promise is not returning before the `console.log($scope.lastSyncTimestap);` line is executed. You can either handle the data within the promise or encapsulate the functionality you wish to do with the data in a function and call that function from within the promise.